# AnimateWindow not calling WM_PAINT

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to animate the display of the rendered window, I have a WM_PRINTCLIENT and WM_PAINT event, but the window is not rendered during the animation, only if RedrawWindow is used after the animation is shown

```
WNDCLASSW Wcc;
MSG Msg;
Wcc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
Wcc.lpfnWndProc = &this->_ChildWndProc;
Wcc.cbClsExtra = 0;
Wcc.cbWndExtra = 0;
Wcc.hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hParent, GWL_HINSTANCE);
hInst_ = (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hParent, GWL_HINSTANCE);
Wcc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
Wcc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
Wcc.hbrBackground = reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH> (CreateSolidBrush(RGB( 255, 255, 255)));
Wcc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
Wcc.lpszClassName = className;
this->className = className;
this->hParent = hWnd;
this->text = text;
this->title = title;
//this->title = title;
windowW = 450;
windowH = 300;

hChild = CreateWindowExW(0, Wcc.lpszClassName, 0, WS_POPUP | WS_MINIMIZEBOX, x, y,
    windowW, windowH, hWnd, NULL, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hParent, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);
loadResources(hChild);
SetWindowLongPtrW(hChild, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG)this);
//SetTransparency(hChild, 0x0f);
//ShowWindow(hChild, SW_SHOW);

AnimateWindow(hChild, 1000, AW_ACTIVATE | AW_BLEND);
```

PAINT:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    Paint(hDlg);
    break;
}
case WM_PRINTCLIENT:
{
    PaintA(hDlg);
    break;
}

Paint(HWND hwnd)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    Graphics graphics(hdc);

    Image image(L"g:\\_project\\image viewer\\ipcamera.jpg");
    graphics.DrawImage(&image, 0, 0);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
}
PaintA(HWND hwnd)
{
    
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
    Graphics graphics(hdc);

    Image image(L"g:\\_project\\image viewer\\ipcamera.jpg");
    graphics.DrawImage(&image, 0, 0);
   
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eRIP.png)

Comment: If you use the same function to handle WM_PAINT and WM_PRINTCLIENT how do you know whether to call BeginPaint/EndPaint, or which DC to render into?

Comment: @JonathanPotter, srry, my bad, iam calling paintA, not paint)

Comment: You are not handling WM_PRINTCLIENT correctly; it gives you the DC to render into as the wParam message parameter.

Comment: @RobY Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have adopted your code, so that I can run it in isolation. I do get debug output `WM_PRINTCLIENT` during animation.

```
void foo(HINSTANCE hInst, HWND hParent) {
    static const wchar_t* className = L"myClassName";
    WNDCLASSW Wcc = {};
    MSG Msg;
    Wcc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    Wcc.lpfnWndProc = ChildWndProc;
    Wcc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    Wcc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    Wcc.hInstance = hInst;
    Wcc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    Wcc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    Wcc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 255));
    Wcc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    Wcc.lpszClassName = className;

    RegisterClassW(&Wcc);

    HWND hChild = CreateWindowW(className, nullptr, WS_POPUP | WS_MINIMIZEBOX, 100, 200, 300, 400, nullptr, nullptr, hInst, nullptr);

    AnimateWindow(hChild, 2000, AW_ACTIVATE | AW_BLEND);
}
```

And here is the window proc I used:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ChildWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        ::OutputDebugString(L"WM_PAINT\n");
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    case WM_PRINTCLIENT:
    {
        ::OutputDebugString(L"WM_PRINTCLIENT\n");
        HDC hdc = (HDC)wParam;
        ::MoveToEx(hdc, 10, 10, nullptr);
        ::LineTo(hdc, 100, 100);
    }
    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
    {
        ::OutputDebugString(L"WM_ERASEBKGND\n");
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE:**

For details, please see WM_PRINTCLIENT message

> A window can process this message in much the same manner as WM_PAINT, except that BeginPaint and EndPaint need not be called (a device context is provided), and the window should draw its entire client area rather than just the invalid region.

Comment: when i use `HDC hdc =  GetDC(hwnd)` its not working, but with  `HDC hdc = (HDC)wParam` its good, what is different GetDC and (HDC)wParam?

Comment: @RobY please see the added `NOTE` in my answer